# Bootstrap Carousel: Store State in Cookie?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to store the state of the Bootstrap carousel.

If user is on the second slide, he clicks on the link and goes to next page, when he comes back I want to maintain the same state of the carousel if the cookie is there.

Comment: if you dont get any other better answer please do accept as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, you have to provide ids to those div containing img tag for image.
For example

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item" id="first_image">
    <img data-src="#" alt="First slide" src="/image_1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="item" id="second_image">
    <img data-src="#" alt="Second slide" src="/image_2.png">
  </div>

  <div class="item" id="third_image">
    <img data-src="#" alt="Third slide" src="/image_3.png">
  </div>    
</div>
```

Now you have to call a common function on that click like : `set_carousel_image_for_cookie()` like that.

Now code to set, retrieve, and delete cookie using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // set cookie  
    var image_id = $('.carousel-inner).find('div').class("active");
    $.cookie('my_carousel_image', image_id);  

    // get cookie  
    alert($.cookie('my_carousel_image'));  

    // delete cookie  
    $.cookie('my_carousel_image', null);  
});
```

On clicking of that link - call `set_carousel_image_for_cookie` function and set cookie.

On page load for the same page, write another function like `check_cookie_for_carousel()` - here detect is their any cookie exist, then get cookie value and set the active class to that specific div.

May be you got some idea to resolve it.